# Ruby Installation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to learn Ruby and i found an warning message in console while installation.

I have installed  Ruby 2.0.0-p481 (x64) and extracted the DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe successfully.

Then i executed following command:

```
chdir C:\DevKit

 ruby dk.rb init

 ruby dk.rb install
```

Then i noticed the following in my console:

```
C:\Users\parthap>chdir C:\DevKit

C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb init
```

> Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
>   'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all of
>   the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

```
C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install
```

> Invalid configuration or no Rubies listed. Please fix 'config.yml' and
>   rerun 'ruby dk.rb install

I am not getting any config.yml file.I can see a config.h file.
and what should be fixed there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Able to install  ruby 1.9.3

previously was trying with Ruby 2.0.0

Ruby 2.0.0, specially the 64bits version, are relatively new on the Windows area and not all the packages have been updated to be compatible with it. To use this version you will require some knowledge about compilers and solving dependency issues, which might be too complicated if you just want to play with the language.

Thanks